# time between ajax send and recieve return negative value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to measure time between sent and recieved ajax request but it often returns negative values.
can anyone explain this weird behavior ?

```
var before = 0;
var after = 0;
$.ajax({
    url: 'data.php',
    type: 'GET',
    beforeSend: function () {
        before = new Date().getMilliseconds();
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        after = new Date().getMilliseconds();
        console.log(after - before);
    },
});
```

Comment: does that date before to 1970 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
beforeSend: function () {
    before = +new Date();
},
success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
    console.log(new Date() - before);
},
```

The problem with the current implementation is that `Date.getMilliseconds()` returns the milleseconds *portion* of the given datetime - that's the number between 0 and 999 [[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMilliseconds)]. But you actually want to compare the 'millisecondsstamp' of the given datetime - and that's what `Date.valueOf()` (or `Date.getTime()`) is for [[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf)]:

> The `valueOf` method returns the primitive value of a Date object as a
>   number data type, the number of milliseconds since midnight 01
>   January, 1970 UTC.

You can omit these calls, however, as `-` operation attempts to cast its operands to primitives (if they're objects) first. So this...

```
console.log(new Date() - before);
```

... will be processed the same as ...

```
console.log(new Date().valueOf() - before);
```

As it makes little sense to store the starting point in `before` as a full Date object, it's cast to a primitive value - with `+` (unary plus) operator.

Comment: Date.getTime() is also handy.

Comment: @naveen This method (`Date.valueOf`) is functionally equivalent to the getTime method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a little confused between `Date.getTime()` and `Date.getMilliSeconds`

getTime is defined as

> Returns the numeric value of the specified date as the number of
>   milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC (negative for prior
>   times).

So, this also works correctly

```
before = new Date().getTime();
```

MDN example for measuring execution time uses this

```
var end, start;

start = new Date();
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  Math.sqrt(i);
end = new Date();

console.log("Operation took " + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()) + " msec");
```